# Sample code for calling Marketo Rest Api in .net/c#

Tags: c#, rest, oauth-2.0, marketo

Does anyone have an example of calling a Marketo Rest API from .net/C#.

I am particularly interested in the oauth authentication piece.
http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/authentication/

I plan to call this endpoint
http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-list-id/

I cannot find any example out there on the interweb.

Comment: There are truly no examples or documentation on calling Market REST api's using .net/C#.   Not sure why someone didn't like the question.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? This is a valid question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to code up a solution for calling a Marketo Rest API and do the OAuth.  Below is a how-to
The below code shows the basics, but needs clean up,  logging and error handling to be production worthy.

You need to get the Rest api URL's for your Marketo instance.  To do this, log into marketo, and navigate to Admin\Integration\Web Services, and use the URLs in the Rest API Section.

You need to get your user id and secret from marketo - navigate to Admin\Integration\Launch Pont.  View the details of your Rest Service to get id and secret.   If you don't have a Service, then follow these instructions http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/custom-service/.

Finally, you need your list id for the list of leads you want to get.  You can get this by navigating to your list and copying the numeric portion of the id out of the url.  Example: https://XXXXX.marketo.com/#ST1194B2 —> List ID = 1194

```
        private void GetListLeads()
    {
        string token = GetToken().Result;

        string listID = "XXXX";  // Get from Marketo UI
        LeadListResponse leadListResponse = GetListItems(token, listID).Result;
        //TODO:  do something with your list of leads

    }
    private async Task<string> GetToken()
    {
        string clientID = "XXXXXX"; // Get from Marketo UI
        string clientSecret = "XXXXXX"; // Get from Marketo UI

        string url = String.Format("https://XXXXXX.mktorest.com/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}",clientID, clientSecret ); // Get from Marketo UI
        var fullUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);

        TokenResponse tokenResponse = new TokenResponse();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(fullUri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                tokenResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<TokenResponse>();
            }
            else
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid username/password combination.");
                else
                    throw new ApplicationException("Not able to get token"); 
            }
        }

        return tokenResponse.access_token;
    }

    private async Task<LeadListResponse> GetListItems(string token, string listID)
    {

        string url = String.Format("https://XXXXXX.mktorest.com/rest/v1/list/{0}/leads.json?access_token={1}", listID, token);// Get from Marketo UI
        var fullUri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Absolute);

        LeadListResponse leadListResponse = new LeadListResponse();
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(fullUri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                leadListResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<LeadListResponse>();
            }
            else
            {
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
                    throw new AuthenticationException("Invalid username/password combination.");
                else
                    throw new ApplicationException("Not able to get token");
            }
        }

        return leadListResponse;
    }


    private class TokenResponse
    {
        public string access_token { get; set; }
        public int expires_in { get; set; }
    }

    private class LeadListResponse
    {
        public string requestId { get; set; }
        public bool success { get; set; }
        public string nextPageToken { get; set; }
        public Lead[] result { get; set; }
    }

    private class Lead
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public DateTime updatedAt { get; set; }
        public string lastName { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public DateTime datecreatedAt { get; set; }
        public string firstName { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Old question, just hoping to help the next guy who ends up here from a google search :-)

This page was probably not there at the time of this post, but there is now a good page with examples in several languages.  The page is at
http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/get-multiple-leads-by-list-id

Just in case the link goes dead, here is the code example that they provide for C#

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Samples
{
    class LeadsByList
    {
        private String host = "CHANGE ME"; //host of your marketo instance, https://AAA-BBB-CCC.mktorest.com
        private String clientId = "CHANGE ME"; //clientId from admin > Launchpoint
        private String clientSecret = "CHANGE ME"; //clientSecret from admin > Launchpoint
        public int listId;
        public int batchSize;//max 300, default 300
        public String[] fields;//array of field names to retrieve
        public String nextPageToken;//paging token
        /*
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            MultipleLeads leads = new MultipleLeads();
            leads.listId = 1001
            String result = leads.getData();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            while (true)
            {

            }
        }
        */
        public String getData()
        {
            StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(host + "/rest/v1/list/" + listId + "/leads.json?access_token=" + getToken());
            if (fields != null)
            {
                url.Append("&fields=" + csvString(fields));
            }
            if (batchSize > 0 && batchSize < 300)
            {
                url.Append("&batchSize=" + batchSize);
            }
            if (nextPageToken != null)
            {
                url.Append("&nextPageToken=" + nextPageToken);
            }
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url.ToString());
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        private String getToken()
        {
            String url = host + "/identity/oauth/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resStream);
            String json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            //Dictionary<String, Object> dict = JavaScriptSerializer.DeserializeObject(reader.ReadToEnd);
            Dictionary<String, String> dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<String, String>>(json);
            return dict["access_token"];
        }
        private String csvString(String[] args)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            int i = 1;
            foreach (String s in args)
            {
                if (i < args.Length)
                {
                    sb.Append(s + ",");
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.Append(s);
                }
                i++;
            }
            return sb.ToString();

        }
    }
}
```

At the time of this response - this page has all of the api calls documented
http://developers.marketo.com/documentation/rest/